# Vanilla JS list selection/hide array

Tags: javascript

I have created an array (list of the cat names) and want to essentially "link" the name to the cat and have it display that individual `img`, caption, and click counter. I'm struggling to figure out the best way to go about it. Right now, I just have it all appended so it's all visible on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>

    <div id="catselector"></div>
<div id="catinfo"></div>

<script>

    var model = {
        currentCat: null,
        catList: [
        {
            title: 'Sassy',
            caption: 'Sassy Cat',
            imgSrc: 'cat.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Grumpy',
            caption: 'Grumpy Cat',
            imgSrc: 'grumpy-cat.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Cuddles',
            caption: 'Cuddling Cats',
            imgSrc: 'cuddles.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sketchy',
            caption: 'Sketchy Cat',
            imgSrc: 'sketchycat.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sneezing',
            caption: 'Sneezing Cat',
            imgSrc: 'sneezingcat.jpg'
        }
    ]
};
    var root = document.querySelector('div#catselector')

    for (var i = 0; i < model.catList.length; i++) {
        root.innerHTML += "<div><ul>"+model.catList[i].title+"</ul></div>"
    }

    var kitty = document.querySelector('div#catinfo')

    for (var i = 0; i < model.catList.length; i++) {
      kitty.innerHTML += "<div><figcaption>"+model.catList[i].caption+"</figcaption><h3 data-count=0>Picture clicks: 0</h3><img src=images/"+model.catList[i].imgSrc+"></div>"
    }

    var catClicks = document.querySelectorAll('img')

    for(var i = 0; i < catClicks.length; i++) {
      catClicks[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var h3 = this.parentNode.querySelector('h3')
        count = parseInt(h3.dataset.count)
        newcount = count += 1

        h3.setAttribute('data-count', newcount)
        h3.innerHTML = "Picture clicks: "+ newcount
      })
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to select a single cat and display it's data? something like this https://jsbin.com/kofezih/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Correct! Only I want to leave it as a <ul> instead of having a drop down menu. I will post the new code I have added, but keep in mind that it's a work in progress so there's a few things in the code might seem pointless.

Comment: I updated my jsbin https://jsbin.com/kofezih/edit?html,js,output .There are lots of improvement still can be done on this code. On your code, one thing I would like to recommend, instead of using anonymous function inside loop, try creating a separate function for click event listener.

Comment: Yeah, this was actually a project for Udacity that took me longer than it probably should have. It was suppose to be teaching about closures and I got to the point where I couldn't figure it out and just wanted to get it done without essentially rewriting the whole code (again). Now to learn Knockout JS!

Comment: Great, you will get better in time. Let me know if I should post this as an answer, also consider learning ReactJs.

Comment: You can post it! It works great for me. You might know the answer to this question: How would I edit the list names? Would it be easier to do in JS or CSS? Mainly just want to make each individual name hoverable (if that makes sense). I'm still pretty new at writing code, so I'm sorry if I sound stupid lol

Comment: I added complete code with hover effect, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code with anchor link and hover effect.

```js
   var model = {
        currentCat: null,
        catList: [
        {
            title: 'Sassy',
            caption: 'Sassy Cat',
            imgSrc: 'cat.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Grumpy',
            caption: 'Grumpy Cat',
            imgSrc: 'grumpy-cat.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Cuddles',
            caption: 'Cuddling Cats',
            imgSrc: 'cuddles.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sketchy',
            caption: 'Sketchy Cat',
            imgSrc: 'sketchycat.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Sneezing',
            caption: 'Sneezing Cat',
            imgSrc: 'sneezingcat.jpg'
        }
    ]
};

    var root = document.querySelector('#selectBox');
 var catInfo = document.querySelector('#catinfo');

    for (var i = 0; i < model.catList.length; i++) {  
  root.innerHTML += "<li ><a href='#' data-id="+i+">"+model.catList[i].title+"<a></li>";
  
    }

function updateCatInfo(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 model.currentCat = model.catList[this.dataset.id];
 var catData = "<div><figcaption>"+model.currentCat.caption+"</figcaption><h3 data-count=0>Picture clicks: 0</h3><img src=images/"+model.currentCat.imgSrc+"></div>";
 //adding cat data
 catInfo.innerHTML = catData;
 //getting cat image
 var catLink = document.querySelector('img');
 //adding event listener on image
 catLink.addEventListener('click', updateCounter);
}


function updateCounter() {
        var h3 = this.parentNode.querySelector('h3')
        count = parseInt(h3.dataset.count)
        newcount = count += 1

        h3.setAttribute('data-count', newcount)
        h3.innerHTML = "Picture clicks: "+ newcount

      }

var allCats = document.querySelectorAll('#selectBox li>a');

allCats.forEach(function(cat){
 cat.addEventListener('click', updateCatInfo)
})
```

```css
body{
 background: #ffffff;
}
li>a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #444;
}
li>a:hover{
 color: #F44336;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Cats</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="selectBox" name="select">
</ul> 
 <div id="catinfo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```